# How do I assign a variable to persist across all job templates in a workflow?

Tags: ansible

I have a workflow and in the first job template I grab some information from a REST endpoint. I want that information to be available to all job templates, plays, and tasks throughout the workflow. I tried `set_fact` and even used `cacheable: true` but once the next job template runs I get `VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!`.

Job template/playbook #1:

```yaml
- name: Get File Contents
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
  - common

  tasks:
    - name: Get File.json
      ansible.builtin.uri:
        url: "{{ repo_uri }}/browse/File.json"
        user: '{{ user }}'
        password: '{{ pass }}'
        method: GET 
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 200
        validate_certs: no
      no_log: false
      register: file_content
    
    - name: Assign file content to a variable
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        file: "{{ file_content.json.lines | map(attribute='text') | join('') }}"
        cacheable: yes
```

Job template/playbook #2

```yaml
---
- name: Check
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
  - common

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: file
```

Job template/playbook #2 result:

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "file": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'file' is undefined. 'file' is undefined"
}
```

The only solution I can think of is to do the same REST call to repeatedly pull the same information for every job template, but that's incredibly redundant and I'd rather not if I can avoid it.

So what's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The attribute [cacheable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html#parameter-cacheable) says:

> ...  converts the variable into an actual ‘fact’ which will also be added to the fact cache.

To use the [fact cache](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/plugins/cache.html#cache-plugins) you have to configure it. For example,

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible_cache
fact_caching_prefix = ''
fact_caching_timeout = 86400
```

The play

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        file: /tmp/test_ansible.txt
        cacheable: true
      when: file is undefined
```

will create the cache

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/ansible_cache/localhost 
{
    "file": "/tmp/test_ansible.txt"
}
```

The play

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: file
```

will read the cache and display the variable

```yaml
  file: /tmp/test_ansible.txt
```

If you don't want the cache to expire set

```ini
fact_caching_timeout = 0
```

Comment: does this apply to Ansible Automation Platform? I tried setting the values you provided in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` but there was no change and it also didn't create the `/tmp/ansible_cache` file.

Comment: Take a look at `shell> ansible-config dump | grep -i cache` and find out which configuration file is to blame.  Your question is similar to: "If it works in C++. Does it apply to Visual Studio?" I won't comment on the Ansible Automation Platform (AAP).  If you have a problem with AAP you should find out first if it works in Ansible. Let's solve the Ansible problem here. Learn how [Configuring Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_configuration.html) works.

Comment: Note that this isn't going to help you in the case that your run playbook 2 BEFORE playbook 1.

Comment: Sure. The question is clear: `"... in the first job template (playbook #1) I grab some information ... want that information to be available to all job templates (playbook #2) throughout the workflow."`

Comment: @VladimirBotka I don't think that's an appropriate comparison. C++ and VS are two completely unrelated products from completely different companies. This is obviously not the case for Ansible/Ansible Automation Platform, which are the same product, but one has a GUI and additional capabilities. That being said, when I ran the config dump while SSH into the AAP it showed the default path of `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` but when I ran it from AAP inside a playbook it showed `CONFIG_FILE() = None`. Do you know where I would put the config file where it can be used by AAP in job templates, etc.?

Comment: I won't comment on APP.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned this two days ago...instead of set_fact, use set_stats

```
  - name: Assign file content to a variable
    ansible.builtin.set_stats:
      data:
        file: "{{ file_content.json.lines | map(attribute='text') | join('') }}"
```

Then use the file variable in your second playbook.